# Can't get Firebase Cloud Messaging to work in my web app

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to work on a web app but so far have failed. Here is what I have in my html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "2yZf4aRzdn6DojuVQ60Vfi4s",
        authDomain: "zavoon-203116.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://zavoon-203116.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "zavoon-203116",
        storageBucket: "zavoon-203116.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "570709736668"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="{{ url('/js/notifications.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        window.notifications = new Notifications();
        notifications.init();
    });
</script>
```

here is my notifications.js file:

```
function Notifications()
{
    var self = this;

    self.init = function()
    {
        // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
        self.messaging = firebase.messaging();

        // Add the public key generated from the console here.
        self.messaging.usePublicVapidKey("BMLVC1zAiawHSriT0zTw-i_ucVTxd0xPlzdRo7m-EzW9HthlO8_bjOM1FXUPwpGgqfoEJYbWzTwJPdsAy_Ta8dc");

        // register a service worker with firebase
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/firebase-service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            self.registration = registration;
            self.messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
            self.requestPermissionAndSaveToken();
        });
    };

    self.sendTokenToServer = function(token)
    {
        $.ajax('/notifications/save/web/token', {
            data: {token: token},
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    };

    self.requestPermissionAndSaveToken = function()
    {
        self.messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
            // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
            // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
            self.messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
                if (currentToken) {
                    self.sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                } else {
                    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token.', err);
            });

            // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
            self.messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
                self.messaging.getToken().then(function(refreshedToken) {
                    self.sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
                });
            });


        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
    };
}
```

here is my firebase-service-worker.js file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '570709736668'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    var notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    var notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

I am using Laravel to register the tokens on the back-end and then I am using [Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) package to sent notifications to the clients. Here is how I exactly sent the notifications, look at the sendNotification method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\NotificationToken;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use LaravelFCM\Facades\FCM;
use LaravelFCM\Message\OptionsBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;

class NotificationsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function saveWebToken(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'type' => 'web',
            'token' => $request->get('token')
        ];

        $notificationToken = new NotificationToken($data);

        if ($notificationToken->save())
        {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'OK']);
        }

        return response()->json(['status' => 'BAD']);
    }

    public function sendNotification()
    {
        $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder('my title');
        $notificationBuilder->setBody('Hello world')
            ->setSound('default');

        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['a_data' => 'my_data']);

        $option = $optionBuilder->build();
        $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();

        $token = NotificationToken::where('user_id', '=', 1)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->first()->token;

        $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);

        $a = $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
        $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
        $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

//return Array - you must remove all this tokens in your database
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete();

//return Array (key : oldToken, value : new token - you must change the token in your database )
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify();

//return Array - you should try to resend the message to the tokens in the array
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry();

        return response()->json(['status' => 'OK', 'success' => $a]);
    }
}
```

notification seems to be sent correctly from my server but I never get it on the client side.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you should delete this ASAP if those are oyur real credentials

Comment: @PhilippSander I've published only my public credentials I think...

Comment: I can only see public creds, nothing wrong with those being published.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem, thanks!

Comment: @SundayGirl if I remember correctly it just started working after waiting a bit which is weird but don't know what else to say